# Apollo is returning data wrong, but is correct in Network inspector

Tags: javascript, apollo

I have a React/Apollo app that keeps getting my data garbled up and wrong. The data looks correct in the Network inspector, but when Apollo returns it, it changes it.

The records that come back should look something like:

```
{
  id: 12345,
  name: 'some record',
  status: { id: 1, name: 'Active' }
  types: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Client' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Example' }
  ],
  // ... more props
}
```

And they DO look like this when I look at the raw response in the Network inspector in Chrome.

The records that Apollo returns however, look like this:

```
{
  id: 12345,
  name: 'some record',
  status: { id: 1, name: 'Client' } // <-- The word "Active" gets changed to "Client"
  types: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Client' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Example' }
  ],
  // ... more props
}
```

I assume Apollo is trying to be all fancy and cool trying to "cache" records or something and it's assuming that the Status IDs and Type IDs are the same. So it's seeing the status.id being 1, so it assumes that's the same as the Type ID of 1.

How do I turn off all of Apollo's fancy stupid "features"?

Edit: Screenshots

This is the raw data printed from the console, the console.log of my `useQuery` hook data:
[image]

This is the raw output that I see in the Network inspector:
[image]

I have no explanation as to why these come out different other than Apollo doing some weird internal logic. It's literally correct in the response, but as soon as Apollo returns it to me it's different.

My code:

```
const { data, refetch } = useQuery(gql`
    query GetScoreAudit(
      $page: Int, $pageSize: Int, $search: String,
      $orderBy: String, $order: Order,
      $status: Int, $type: Int
    ) {
      scoreAudit(
        page: $page, pageSize: $pageSize, search: $search,
        orderBy: $orderBy, order: $order,
        status: $status, type: $type
      ) {
        total
        nodes {
          id
          name
          managedWorkstations
          managedServers
          firewall
          wpsCompliance
          maxWpsCompliance
          mrr
          tpe
          status {
            id
            name
          }
          types {
            id
            name
          }
          serviceCompanies {
            service
            exists
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `, {
    variables: {
      page: tableOpts.pagination.page,
      pageSize: tableOpts.pagination.pageSize,
      search: tableOpts.filters.search,
      orderBy: tableOpts.orderBy,
      order: tableOpts.order,
      status: tableOpts.filters.status,
      type: tableOpts.filters.type
    }
  });

  console.log(data);
```

Stringified output data:
[image]

Comment: That's a pretty huge assumption that doesn't really seem plausible. Could you please [edit] your question to show the code you're using including any debugging / logging statements and if possible, add screenshots of the logging from your console and the response from the _Network_ panel

Comment: @Phil Screenshots posted

Comment: @Phil There I've posted my useQuery hook. Not sure what that helps you with. The server is definitely correct because the data it's returning is right. There is literally NONE of my code in-between apollo returning it and me reading it. I'm not touching it at all.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` instead? You might be (inadvertently) mutating the data somewhere after this code and Chrome's console shows live versions of objects

Comment: It’d probably be helpful to show your query, particularly its `fetchPolicy`. Tangential: calling it “stupid” isn’t a great approach.

Comment: @Phil Posted, still the same

Comment: @DaveNewton Query is posted. And sorry, but I've been pulling my hair out all day over this and it doesn't make any sense. I've narrowed down every possibility already and I'm 100% certain it's Apollo doing this.

Comment: You have the same `CWBaseRecord` (with the same `id`) twice, but with different values. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Bergi Just now finding that out from the new answer below, thanks. My server does not allow me to define two different types with the same schema though. I'm using postgraphile on the server.

Comment: @chrispytoes What do you mean by "*two different types with the same schema*"? Talking of Postgraphile, is `cw_base_record` a table? Or a composite `type`, and you have custom resolvers for the `status` and `types` fields?

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, technically this just has to do with graphile itself. These are custom types I defined for my own resolvers yes, and it throws an error on build, like a generic "Oops! Did you mean 'this' type?" kind of error.

Comment: @chrispytoes Please [create a new question](/questions/ask) where you show your graphile setup, the schema, the resolvers, and the whole build error message. You really should fix this issue on the server side, not turn off the (very useful) cache normalisation. Are these two objects (supposed to be) representing the same entity? If yes, why do they have different names? If no, why do they have the same type and id?

Comment: @Bergi They do not represent the same entity, they just so happen to have the same properties. I've already posted an issue on the graphile-engine github suggesting that this should not be an error. I don't mind even turning off the cache entirely, it's caused me more trouble than it's worth and this app doesn't need to be instantly fast or anything, it's an internal use app.

Comment: Seems like your [github issue](https://github.com/graphile/graphile-engine/issues/857) was not well received, it's not the graphile-engine throwing this error. It might help if you could post a [mcve] either there or in a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Apollo Client's normalized cache - you can (and probably should) [read more about it in the documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/overview).

Generally: if Apollo Client encounters two objects with the same combination of `__typename:id`, it considers them to be "the same object", stores them in the same place and merges them together.

So in your case, both of these items have the "internal id" `CWBaseRecord:1` - and the *best* thing you could do would be to make sure that your server actually returns different id/type combinations for things that are not the same.

If you cannot do that, you could add a type policy for `CWBaseRecord` that states that they should not be normalized:

```
      const client = new ApolloClient({
        // ...
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
          typePolicies: {
            CWBaseRecord: {
              keyFields: false,
            },
          },
        }),
      });
```

Comment: I knew I wasn't crazy! I was being told that was impossible... Problem is, my server does not allow me to define two different types with the same schema. It throws an error if I try to do that. Disabling key fields for that type does work though, thanks!